# Android AlarmManager in a Broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have braodcastreceiver, that broadcast receiver shall schedule an alarm.

Usually I would do

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, time,  myPendingIntent);
```

The problem is that getSystemService is not available in a Broadcast receiver only in an Activty. How would I do it here?

Thanks, A.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

AndyAndroid,

`getSystemService()` is part of the `Context`.  You will need to save the `Context` you receive in your `onReceive()` method like so...

```
private Context mContext;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
    mContext = c;
}
```

Then..where you call `getSystemService()` you use...

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

Comment: thanks, thats 70% ;-) it has to be AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) c.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Comment: ah >< right that constant is part of Context as well...lemme fix that!

Comment: @WilliamTate : I have registered a intent filter with action BOOT_COMPLETED for my broadcast receiver. So when the phone restarts how will the application context be passed along (will it be passed along, first of all?)?

Comment: @Ashwin the context will be passed along in your `BroadcastReceiver` by the function onReceive().  The arguments will be the context and the intent. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html EDIT: Unfortunately deep linking doesn't work when I paste the link, just search that page for `onReceive`